# Populating a listview with a database

Tags: android, database, android-listview

The following code is to return a string to print the entries in a text view in the display activity, but it does that by sending all the entries at once, so I am not able to handle one at a time.

This is the function used in database to return data.

```
public String getData() {

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
                KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR };

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);        
            String result = "";

        // int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);  
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);     
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);     
        int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH);   
        int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);     
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) 
            {             
            result = result + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\t\t"
         + c.getString(iDate) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iMonth)+ "\t\t" + c.getString(iYear) + "\n";

        }       
           return result;   
           }
```

This is the class to print the entries in the text view:

```
    public class DBView extends Activity {

        TextView tv;

        @Override   
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.dbview);

            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SQLinfo); 
            DataBaseClass info = new DataBaseClass(this);       
            info.open();        
            String data = info.getData();       
            info.close();       
            tv.setText(data);

           }

       }
```

What I am trying to do is to make a list view according to number of entries in the database. For example, if there is only one entry, only one list item is generated containing name, date, month & year. I tried using string adapters and list adapters, but could not get them to work.

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
                KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR };

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);        
            String result = "";

        // int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);  
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);     
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);     
        int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH);   
        int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);   
        ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) 
            {             
            result = c.getString(iName) + "\t\t"
         + c.getString(iDate) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iMonth)+ "\t\t" + c.getString(iYear) + "\n";
         string_array.add(result);

        }       
           return string_array;   
   }
```

and..

```
public class DBView extends Activity {

        ListView lv;

        @Override   
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.dbview);

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);  
            DataBaseClass info = new DataBaseClass(this);       
            info.open();        
            ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();       
            info.close();       
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
           }

       }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly....i just edited one thing in the getData function...removed result from 

result = 'result' + strings..

Now i m using result = String
Then placing it in the array...Thanx a lot

Comment: you are right! I have edited the answer following your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return the last entry in the database only (no matter if you loop through the cursor, it will return the last result). You can instead use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` (Specify columns and `TextViews` to fill from the columns). Check this sample:

```
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);        
        String result = "";

SimpleCursorAdapter adap=new SimpleCursorAdapter (getApplicationContext, /*create layout with 4 TextViews*/, c, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR }, int[] /*ids of the 5 TextViews from the layout part in an int[]*/);
```

Then create a `ListView` to display your data:

```
ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(/*ListView id in your main layout*/);
lv.setAdapter(adap);
```